Правильно ли ответила Грамота?
Добрый день. Нужны ли запятые в предложении Северную столицу России город Санкт-Петербург основал царь Пётр Первый.
ОТВЕТ:
Оборот город Санкт-Петербург можно выделить запятыми, а можно поставить перед ним тире.
https://gramota.ru/spravka/vopros/310430
То есть Грамота предлагает написать так:
Северную столицу России - город Санкт-Петербург основал царь Пётр Первый.
А разве двойное тире здесь не обязательно?

Правильно:
Северную столицу России — город Санкт-Петербург / основал царь Пётр Первый.
Пояснение

В данном случае приложение обособляется не запятыми, а тире, но при этом второе тире опускается.  Тогда речевой оборот Северную столицу России — город Санкт-Петербург произносится  как единая конструкция с небольшой произносительной пузой на месте тире. Фактически мы имеем интонацию простого предложения.

Такой вариант возможен, если приложение выражает конкретное значение, а предшествующее определяемое слово имеет общее или образное значение.


Розенталь
10. При обособлении приложений вместо запятой употребляется 
тире:
Примечание. Одно тире (первое или второе) опускается:
2) если приложение выражает конкретное значение, а 
предшествующее определяемое слово имеет общее или образное 
значение: 
На совещании министров иностранных дел стран — членов 
Организации американских государств выступил министр 
иностранных дел Кубы (Газ.); Прилетели сюда первые ласточки 
— наши спортсмены для участия в парусных гонках; Высшая 
награда Французского института океанографии за выдающиеся 
океанографические работы — медаль в память Альберта I принца 
Монакского присуждена видному учёному Л. А. Зенькевичу 
(Газ.);

